# give custom roles for administrator only ,so problem in displaying other menus in admin panel

Tags: admin-panel, user-roles

[image]i went  to system > configuration > users .

i select "Administrators" and than "custom" than i selected some dashboard", newsletter and click on save.

now when i open admin panel with administrator, its showing only "dashboard" and "sales" and "system"

menu. please help me to find how to get back the other menus in admin panel.

[image]

Comment: You added those permissions to your own admin user or did you created another user?

Comment: no, by mistake only own admin itself....

Comment: I just add the link on how to reset roles https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-reset-magento-admin-user-role-and-resources-permission-to-all.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the following queries to reset it:

```
DELETE FROM admin_rule WHERE role_id = 1 AND resource_id != 'all';
UPDATE admin_rule SET permission = 'allow' WHERE role_id = 1;
```

This is assuming that the Administrator role_id is 1.

Comment: hi, thanks.... instead of running queries, can you please help me to do manually?

Comment: please see the image in the question and help me....

Comment: This is what you need @BabyinMagento2. Copy the query and put it in your SQL tab in phpMyAdmin. Click run and that is it.

Comment: You will need access to the database in order to do this. AFAIK, you cannot reset permissions using the Magento Admin only.

Answer (score 1):

In your database there are 4 tables regarding admin roles, users and rule. Open the table admin_role and from there you will be able to change the role the admin user have.
My user looks like this:

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks a lot, i got that. what next i have to do to get all menus in admin panel.

Comment: please see the image in the question and help me....